# Casting 32 bit pointer to 64 bit pointer? (causing copy_from_user to fail)

Tags: c, linux, pointers, casting, linux-kernel

I'm working with the linux kernel, and I have a usermode program that's trying to send an ioctl to kernel. I get the ioctl fine, but my copy_from_user is failing, presumably because of the pointer being wrong.

The user mode program is compiled as 32-bit, whereas the kernel is running in 64-bit.

User mode:

```
user_test_input *input_test = (user_test_input*)malloc(sizeof(user_test_input));
// container->ptr is defined as uint64_t, even though this is 32-bit user mode
container->ptr = (uint64_t)input_test;
printf("ptr: 0x%016X", container->ptr);

//send ioctl(fd, COMMAND, container);
```

This outputs: **0x00000000F82DF038**

Kernel mode:

```
test_input *kernel_input_data = (test_input *)kmalloc(sizeof(test_input), GFP_KERNEL);
copy_from_user(kernel_input_data, (void __user*)data->ptr, sizeof(test_input));
```

The value I'm seeing for data->ptr is: **0xfffffffff82df038**

Am I doing something wrong? My copy_from_user is failing. I was thinking that it had to do with the 0x00000000XXXXXXXX vs 0xFFFFFFFFXXXXXXXX.

Thanks!

Comment: The only thing I can think about is copy_from_user(__input_data, (void __user*)data->ptr, 4); kernel_input_data=(uint_64)__input_data, but I cannot test it now... having only 32 bit machines in here

Comment: Are you going through `compat_ioctl`? I mean, I don't think you are supposed to cast to u64 from the application directly. There is an in-Kernel translation mechanism for that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running into a signed-issue.  Because `0xF82DF038` has the top bit set, it is regarded as negative and when it gets promoted from a 32 bit value to a 64 bit value, that top bit is repeated to fill the new space, so in the end you get `0xfffffffff82df038`.

To avoid that, use unsigned data types.

Consider the types of `container->ptr` and of `data->ptr`.

Comment: container->ptr is defined as uint64_t, as is data->ptr. How would you recommend casting it so that it doesn't interpret the 0xF82DF038 as negative?

Comment: Tricky.  `(unsigned long long) (unsigned long) data->ptr` or `(uint64_t) (uint32_t) data->ptr` _should_ cast it first to an unsigned type and then promote it to 64 bits.

Comment: Probably best to do (uint64_t)(unsigned long) actually. Thanks